# Automatically enable cursor shadow

Tags: windows-xp, cursor

Some programs disable the desktop cursor shadow without re-enabling it. I'm looking for a solution to automatically enable it, preferably at all times. Perhaps a registry setting that keeps it enabled. Or a program that checks every few seconds whether it is enabled and if not, enables it.

Comment: [This page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/ITCG/thread/3d2472d6-973b-4125-ba7e-41602aa3b51b) discusses the **UserPreferencesMask** value in the registry, and you can get working code to toggle the cursor shadow state [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754635/script-to-enable-mouse-shadow) and [here](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_general/miscellaneous/article.php/c15755/Changing-Mouse-Settings-With-VBNET.htm).

Comment: @Karan Not much I can do with code; that would be more appropriate for stackoverflow. I need a working solution I can deploy.